# Problem installing nvidia driver with ubuntu-drivers command 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, xubuntu

After running `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`
I confirmed the following available drivers

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
...
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 OEM]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

But upon running `sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-450`, I get

```
No drivers found for installation.
```

Oddly enough I am able to find `nvidia-driver-450` by running `apt install nvidia-driver-450` but I would like to use `ubuntu-drivers`. How can this be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: running sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450 will install the Ubuntu driver the command(ubuntu-drivers devices) simply shows what drivers are available on the Ubuntu repo for your devices

Answer (score 1):

Install the driver from `Software & Update` application.

After opening it go to Additional drivers tab and install the recommended driver (**driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party free recommended** in your case)